# How to set a core-data attibute to nil, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, null, nsnull

Here is a working Swift function I have:

```
func myColorFuntion (object:NSManagedObject) -> UIColor {
    if (object.valueForKey("bgColor") == nil) {return UIColor.yellowColor()}
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(object.valueForKey("bgColor") as! NSData) as! UIColor
}
```

My question relates to the line with the “if” statement. `object.valueForKey("bgColor")` starts with a nil value because it has not been defined.
I can set something not nil for `object.valueForKey("bgColor")` with code like the following and it works.

```
let theColorData:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(UIColor.cyanColor())
var object:NSManagedObject
object.setValue(theColorData forKey:"bgColor")
```

But how can I set `object.valueForKey("bgColor")` back to nil? The few trials I made using nil and NSNull didn’t work.

`

Comment: Why not use transparent, or a default colour of your choosing instead of null?

Comment: Also, what sort of object are you referring to here? A button, the background, a textview?

Comment: What happened when you tried `object.setValue(nil, forKey:"bgColor")`?

Comment: Thanks, Marcus's answer works. I had tried before but failed because I was not doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, try:

```
object.setNilValueForKey("your attribute name")
```